# JNI UnsatisfiedLinkError dependent libraries

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I have a JNI dll along with a jar file that I have created on a machine with eclipse.

I am trying to deploy this to another machine and cannot get past the exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\CcmAccess\CcmJNIBase.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
        at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Meth
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
        at com.sig.ccm.CcmBase.<clinit>(CcmBase.java:8)
        at ReadTimeDomain.setupSample(ReadTimeDomain.java:24)
        at ReadTimeDomain.main(ReadTimeDomain.java:97)
```

I have another program that prints out the java.library.path and I have verified the dll that this dll depends on as well as this dll are in the java.library.path.

I have read posts where they should go in the current directory and that doesn't work.

I have read posts where they should go in the jre/bin and that gets the same result.

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit:

If I take everything out of the path and force the classpath to only have the jar file and "." I get the message

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no CcmJNIBase in java.library.path
```

When I add the location of this dll into the path C:\CcmAccess I get the full message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\CcmAccess\CcmJNIBase.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
```

On the machine that this seems to work all I had to do was add the dependent dll to my classpath.

Comment: Are you using an absolute path in your java.library.path?

Answer (score 0):

Double check your java.library.path value.
Make sure that you are using an absolute path.
Relative paths will make you think your java.library.path is correct, when actually it is actually incorrect.

If you are adding "." in your java.library.path, then you need to double check the "current working directory" when you execute your code.

If you need to use a relative path in your java.library.path, make sure that the path is relative from the "working directory" when you execute your code.

Comment: I am only using absolute paths.  I have the JNI dll explicitly named on the path and I have the directory it is in named on the path.  The last element on java.library.path is ".".

Comment: The JNI dll and the native dll are in the same directory.  I have tried naming each of them explicitly, and that doesn't help.  What do you mean by double check the "current working directory"?

Comment: If the message is  C:\CcmAccess\CcmJNIBase.dll: Can't find dependent libraries.  Is it looking for CcmJNIBase or the dll it depends on?

Comment: It is looking for CCmJNIBase.dll. Do you have it on the "other machine"?

Comment: It is created on the other machine.  On the machine I am trying to deploy on if I ask windows to find the file it finds: C:\CcmAccess\CcmJNIBase.dll.  In my path I have C:\CcmAccess;C:\CcmAccess\CcmJNIBase.dll;.

Comment: It seems strange that it reports the dll it can't find with the complete correct path to the dll.

Comment: I have a local java class that imports classes from the jar file.  I use javac MyClass.java and it seems to work correctly.  Then I use java MyClass to attempt to execute.

Comment: Have you tried something this: java -Djava.library.path:/path/to/your.jar -classpath /path/to/ MyClass

Comment: I just did and the result is exactly the same.  I am going to try on a different computer.